# Why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to copy an array from stdin to a 2d array?

Tags: c, gcc, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

This is in relation to the HackerRank Restaurant problem, which I have solved in other languages but am trying, now, to solve in C.https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/restaurant

I first tried to store the result if `read_slice_dimension()` directly into the multidimensional array, but because I cannot pass an array back from a function without making it static, this does not work because then every nested array points to the same static 2 integer array in memory, which, as a result of it being overwritten every time `read_slice_dimension()` is called, means I would have an array containing `num_slices` pointers to the last array read in from stdin.

Thus my decision to try `memcpy`, so that I could copy the arry from `read_slice_dimension()` to a new block of memory so that it persists and is not lost when I read in the next slice.  It appears, however, that `memcpy` is not the way to do this.  What is?

```
// Gets the number of slices for this test according to the first input value from stdin.
int read_num_slices() {
  int num_slices = 0;

  scanf("%i", &num_slices);

  if (num_slices == 0) {
    goto error;
  }

  return num_slices;

error:
  flag_error("ERROR: Could not parse the number of entries from first input line.");
}

// Gets a single line from stdin and attempts to parse it into a 2D int array representing the dimensions of a slice.
int* read_slice_dimension() {
  static int slice_dimension[2] = {0};

  scanf("%i %i", &slice_dimension[0], &slice_dimension[1]);

  if (slice_dimension[0] + slice_dimension[1] == 0) {
    goto error;
  }

  return slice_dimension;

error:
  flag_error("ERROR: Could not parse line entered into a 2 integer array representing the slice's dimensions.");
}

// Gets all of the bread slices to be processed.
//
// This function reads from stdin.  The first line should be a single integer that specifies the number of slices to be
// processed by this current test.  The subsequent lines should be two integers separated by a space which represent
// the 2D dimensions of each slice.
int** get_slices() {
  int num_slices = read_num_slices();
  static int** slices;
  slices = (int**)malloc(num_slices * sizeof(int*));

  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < num_slices; i++) {
    int* slice = slices[i];
    slice = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(slice, read_slice_dimension(), 2 * sizeof(int));
    printf("%i %i\n", slices[i][0], slices[i][1]); // CAUSES SEGMENTATION FAULT
  }

  return slices;
}
```

Comment: `static int slice_dimension[2] = {0};` is not a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @zmb The bug is in the `get_slices()` function, which attempts to create an array of `slice_dimension`s, which would be 2D.

Comment: You're setting `slice = slices[i]`, then calling `malloc`. That's backwards. Call `malloc`, then set `slices[i]`.

Comment: @user3386109

That was it.  If you add that comment as a proper answer, I'll select it as the correct one so that you can get credit.

Comment: Glad that worked for you, but I think this falls into the category of "a simple typographical error ... unlikely to help future readers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `slice = slices[i]`, then calling `malloc`. That's backwards. Call `malloc`, then set `slices[i]`.
                    – user3386109